# iPhone programming guideline : List / detail / modify

Tags: iphone, listview, coding-style

I have a program that displays a list (a TableView).
When the user clicks an item, it's detail is shown.
On the detail view, the user can ask to modify it so a modify window is shown.
Here, the user can ask to delete the item.
I would like at this time return to the list with the item deleted from the list and from the data source.

There may be thousands of methods to do this, but I wonder which is the best / good one.

Could you help me, and/or give me a good reference to read about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at least Two options:

1. Delegation - Create a protocol called something like: TableDetailModifierDelegat
   and add methods like `modifierDidChangedItem:(id)item`
   or `modifierDidDeleteItem:(id)item`

and to the modifying view controller add instance variable id so when you done editing or deleting you will call the appropriate methods.

of course you will need to make your table view controller implement the protocol you created. if you modified or deleted an item you should update your data source and reload the data to the table. 
also pass the Table View Controller as the delegate when creating the Modifying View Controller.

1. Passing The Data Model.
   This is much more simple to implement.
   you can simply pass your data model to the modifying view controller, and make the changes directly to the data model.
   You should keep the data model as Instance Variable in the modifying view controller.
   when you done, dont forget to reload the data to your table.

Comment: would you have a retain or assign instance variable in the 3rd view ?

Comment: I would certainly retain. although it is almost sure that the data model will live longer than the modifying view controller, I find it very efficient to retain object that i extensively use, and the best way to do it without risking any leaks is using them as properties.

Answer (score 2):

I think he ask how to get from view number 3 back to first view.
Then you can put your three views inside a `UINavigationController` and call on the last view `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, you could simply remove the data from the data source the [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is using and then call the reloadData method on the table. (As you're editing the data in question, you'll presumably have a suitable method/reference by which to delete it.)

As a bit of reading, I'd recommend Apple's [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) - this provides a lot of useful background information.